# Pyramid json view ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, pyramid

I have never really worked with ajax before, so would you please be elaborate in your answers..

I have a Pyramid application where I want to load information via ajax because pre-loading it would not be feasible.  So I want to load the information I need through a pyramid view, but I am unsure how to do this.
The information I need to fetch is in a MySQL database, so I guess I need to import the mouse click event object `ajax_id` into views.py in order to do the query. (I can get ajax_id without a problem)

In my views.py I have:

```
@view_config(route_name="info_ajax",renderer="json")
def info_ajax(self):

    #for the sake of this example, lets just return the information from the mouse click event
    A = ajax_id      #is the id of the mouse click event
    B = ajax_name    #is the name of the mouse click event

    return {
                'a' : A,
                'b' : B,
        }
```

What I would usually do is to preload all information, but that would take to long in this case, so I cannot just make a list of MySQL queries in views.py and then do `<script>window.coords = ${a|query_list};</script>` in my .mak file.

I want to import `a` and `b` in my JavaScript code as variables, so that I can use them again without having to reload them if need be.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Usually you return a dictionary or something that can be serialized to JSON from a view that uses a JSON renderer. The renderer converts to JSON itself. Easy for you and easier to test in test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to do it:

in pyramid view.py:

```
@view_config(route_name="info_ajax",renderer="json")
def info_ajax(self):

    #for the sake of this example, lets just return the information from the mouse click event

    A = self.request.POST.get('ajax_id')    #is the id of the mouse click event
    B = self.request.POST.get('ajax_name')   #is the name of the mouse click event

    return {
                'ID' : A,
                'Name' : B,
        }
```

and in JS:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "details",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'ajax_id': iID,
            'ajax_name': sName,
        },
        success: function(data) {
                iReturned_value = data.ID;
            }, 
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already an official pyramid tutorial giving enough background to solve basic AJAX tasks.

- [Creating a Custom UX for Pyramid - Step 09: AJAX With JSON Views](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-tutorials/en/latest/search.html?q=AJAX&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

You need more tutorials?

- [Available Pyramid tutorials](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-tutorials/en/latest/index.html)

My favorite advanced tutorial is ToDoPyramid (a Github fork)

- https://github.com/saschagottfried/todopyramid